# Cleaning string using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove a specific word from a string using Regex and JavaScript. I have strings like below

```
Zoe-Clean-1-1024x678
Zoe-Clean-1-150x150
Zoe-Clean-1-1536x1017
Zoe-Clean-1-1700x1126
Zoe-Clean-1-2048x1356
Zoe-Clean-1-300x199
Zoe-Clean-1-768x509
Zoe-Clean-1-900x596
Zoe-Clean-1-scaled
Zoe-Clean-1
zoko-150x150
zoko-300x300
Zoo-Studio-Logo-for-Pay-150x150
Zoo-Studio-Logo-for-Pay-300x300
Zoo-Studio-Logo-for-Pay-768x768
Zoo-Studio-Logo-for-Pay
```

I want to remove the `Logo, for, Pay, scaled` word, resolution size `150x150, 300x300, etc.`, and remove the dash character `-`. So I expect I can only get the main name.

```
Zoe-Clean-1 -> Zoe Clean
Zoe-Clean-1-scaled -> Zoe Clean
Zoe-Clean-1-300x199 -> Zoe Clean
Zoo-Studio-Logo-for-Pay -> Zoo Studio
Zoo-Studio-Logo-for-Pay-768x768 -> Zoo Studio
```

Currently, I'm using this code `name.replace(/\b(Logo|for|Pay)\b/gm, "")`, I don't know how to remove the dash and resolution size.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = name.replace(/(Logo|for|Pay|[0-9]+x[0-9]+|-[0-9]+[-|$|\s])/gm, "") ;
name = name.replace(/-/gm, " ") ;
name = name.trim() ;
```

First, remove all we don't want : `[0-9]+x[0-9]+` match the resolution size, `-[0-9]+[-|$|\s]` match number with à dash before and a dash after **or** à line break/line end.
Then you replace all the - by space : `name.replace(/-/gm, " ")`.
So you just have to trim() the string !

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
name = name.replace(/-Logo-for-Pay|-\d.*/g, '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/umka8F/1)

*Details*:

- `-Logo-for-Pay` - a fixed substring
- `|` - or
- `-\d.*` - a hyphen, a digit and then the rest of the line.